# Error al crear objetos

Tags: java

Buenas noches, me encargarón realizar un programa sencillo en la clase de POO en cual consiste en hacer un sencillo programa en el cual consiste en un Banco en donde se puede ingresar o retirar dinero. Lo hice en 2 clases, pero en la segunda clase no me deja declarar objetos private, solo me sirve si creo los objetos dentro del metodo main y sin el private.

Clase 1:

```
public class Cuenta{
    private String titular;
    private double saldo;

    public Cuenta(String nombre, double dinero){
        titular = nombre;
        saldo = dinero;
    }
    public void ingresar(double dinero){
        saldo = saldo + dinero;
    }
    public void retirar(double dinero){
        if(dinero<=saldo)
            saldo = saldo-dinero;
    }
    public double checar(double dinero){
        return saldo;
    }
}
```

Clase 2:

```
public class Banco{
    private Cuenta cuenta1 = new Cuenta("Carlos Carrete", 2500);
    private Cuenta cuenta2 = new Cuenta("Daniela Pabon", 200);

    public static void main (String [] args){
        cuenta1.ingresar(200);
        cuenta2.ingresar(100);

        cuenta1.retirar(100);
    }
}
```

En la clase 2 sale "non static variable cannot be referend from a static context

Comment: Prueba a declarar los objetos cuenta tambien como static, junto a private.

Comment: la clase main() es static, solo define como static las instancias de cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

Si, el error es así por que desde métodos estaticos solo puedes hacer referencia a otros métodos estaticos o a variables estaticas. Lo que debes hacer es crear el objeto dentro del método estatico y así poder hacer uso de sus atributos

```
public class Banco{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Cuenta cuenta1 = new Cuenta("Carlos Carrete", 2500);
        Cuenta cuenta2 = new Cuenta("Daniela Pabon", 200); 
        cuenta1.ingresar(200);
        cuenta2.ingresar(100);

        cuenta1.retirar(100);
    }
}
```

Si deseas hacer con objetos lo puedes hacer así

```
public class Banco{
  public Cuenta cuenta1 = new Cuenta("Carlos Carrete", 2500);
  public Cuenta cuenta2 = new Cuenta("Daniela Pabon", 200);

  public static void main (String [] args){
    Banco banco = new Banco();
    banco.cuenta1.ingresar(200);
    banco.cuenta2.ingresar(100);

    banco.cuenta1.retirar(100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Los métodos usados no son definidos como `static` dentro de la clase `Cuenta`,

```
public class Cuenta{
    private String titular;
    private double saldo;

    public Cuenta(String nombre, double dinero){
        titular = nombre;
        saldo = dinero;
    }
    public void ingresar(double dinero){
        saldo = saldo + dinero;
    }
    public void retirar(double dinero){
        if(dinero<=saldo)
            saldo = saldo-dinero;
    }
    public double checar(double dinero){
        return saldo;
    }
}
```

para usarlos dentro de `main()` puedes definir las variables como static, de esta forma llamar los métodos sin problema dentro de `main()`:

```
 public class Banco {

   private static Cuenta cuenta1 = new Cuenta("Carlos Carrete", 2500);
   private static Cuenta cuenta2 = new Cuenta("Daniela Pabon", 200);

   public static void main(String[] Args) {

         cuenta1.ingresar(200);
         cuenta2.ingresar(100);
         cuenta1.retirar(100);

    }


}
```